Long computation time of torch.autograd.functional.jacobian
Im using scipy least squares to find best rotation from one sensor to another; After rotation, I project the points to an image and compare them with some ground truth.
The problem I'm facing is the long time of one jacobian iteration, about one minute for 700 points.
Data is originally pytorch tensors.
The code is as follow:
from typing import Union
import numpy as np
import torch
from pytorch3d.transforms import quaternion_apply
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from torch.autograd.functional import jacobian
TENSOR_OR_NUMPY = Union[torch.Tensor, np.ndarray]

def project(x0: TENSOR_OR_NUMPY) -> torch.Tensor:
    if isinstance(x0, np.ndarray):
        quaternion = torch.tensor(x0, dtype=torch.float32).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    else:
        quaternion = x0
    xc = quaternion_apply(quaternion, points3d)
    xh = xc / xc[:, 2:3]
    image_points = xh @ K.T
    delta = image_points[:, :2] - points2d_gt
    delta_norm = torch.linalg.norm(delta, dim=1)
    return delta_norm

def jacobian_func(quaternion: np.ndarray):
    quaternion = torch.tensor(quaternion, dtype=torch.float32).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    jac = jacobian(project,quaternion)#, create_graph=True)
    return jac.detach().numpy()

q0 = torch.Tensor([0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5])
res_rt = least_squares(project,q0,jac=jacobian_func)

So first of all I want to know if it is logical that it takes so long. Second, How can I speed this up?
Thanks!
